# Sorting a List of IP Strings to Numbers with a Blank Entry

Tags: c#, list, sorting, lambda

I have a list of IP addresses that were grabbed as strings and I am sorting.  While sorting the list I am converting the strings to integers as well as replacing the "." most commonly seen in IP addresses with "".  This can be seen below.

```
ipAddresses.Sort((a, b) => Convert.ToInt64(a.Address.Trim().Replace(".", "")).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt64(b.Address.Trim().Replace(".", ""))));
```

The issue is that I reach an entry that throws a "System.FormatException" error.  The full error is as follows.

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

When I look at the entry that is throwing the error it's IP address is empty so I'm assuming that that empty IP address is causing this error.

My question is how should I handle empty strings while sorting my list?

Comment: You could use the ternary operator `?` `:` or you could perhaps simply add a `"0"` to the start of the string.

Comment: But you may need to consider left-padding each octet so 1.1.1.1 > 0.255.255.255 (unless you prefer that in your rules)

Comment: @IanMercer where are you suggesting I put the `?` or `:`?  I'm not entirely familiar with those operators, only used them a few times.  Also if I add a 0 to the start of my string won't that mess with the entries that actually have a value?

Comment: @JasonW I'm not clear on what you mean by "left-padding"

Comment: @blueberry I tried to clarify in answer below.

Comment: This is very simple : ipAddresses = ipAddresses.OrderBy(x => BitConverter.ToUInt32(x.GetAddressBytes(), 0)).ToList();

Comment: You realize, I hope, that by just removing the periods, you can end up with odd things like `10.22.3.12` and `10.2.23.12` being equal. Both end up as `1022312`.

Comment: @JimMischel to be honest I hadn't actually thought of that so thanks for pointing it out.  I guess I'll need to change some things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one (of many) techniques to convert to numeric values. You can have a simple method to convert the ip to a number. You can then have that method have special cases of null, empty string, or invalid ip addresses so you can select whether those go to top or bottom of your list.

Whichever technique you choose, you need to have some acceptable method to give proper significance to each octet of the IP so that "1.1.1.1" is considered a larger value than "0.255.255.255" since simply collapsing the values puts "1111" < "255,255,255" otherwise.

```
public static int GetValue(string ip)
{
    IPAddress parsed;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out parsed))
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(parsed.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
    else
        return int.MaxValue; // Or min value if you want invalid ips at beginning
}
```

Then your sort method becomes

```
ipAddresses.Sort((a,b) => GetValue(a).CompareTo(GetValue(b)));
```

Link to .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wgCzOL

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out empty item from the list by using Where

```
ipAddresses.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Address)).ToList().Sort((a, b) => Convert.ToInt64(a.Address.Trim().Replace(".", "")).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt64(b.Address.Trim().Replace(".", ""))));
```